# Execute a php file when click inside an href area in html file?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have two files:

1. A HTML file named `index.html`
2. A PHP file named `update-db.php`, which contains code for updating a particular database

I want to execute the PHP file (eg. `update-db.php`) whenever user clicks on a specific `<a href` tag with the `id="clicks"`

Comment: do some ajax call to that update-db.php file from  index.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery Ajax to give request to that page

```
$("#clicks").click( function () {
$.ajax({
      url: "url of php file eg:(localhost/update-db.php)",
      method: 'POST',
      data: {update:true},                 
      success: function (data) {
                 alert(data);
      },
  });  
});
```

at the same time use a validation in in your php file `update-db.php`

```
if($_POST['update']=='true'){
    Your Complete PHP Function you want to run
}
```

after all, 
Your page will alert what this PHP file says 
For Example : if you `echo "Updated Database";` 
page will alert it;

Hope you the point